# JQuery load local files dynamically

Tags: jquery, load

I am developing a HTML prototype, all the static content in the page is saved in different files. I want to use these files as includes in my HTML prototype.
Below is HTML code for calling the two HTML include files.

```
<div class="include-file" file="header.html"></div>
<div class="include-file" file="footer.html"></div>
```

I am using jquery load() method to include these files.

```
$(function () {
    var fileName = $(".include-file").attr('file');
     $(".include-file").load(fileName);
});
```

This function works fine when i am including only one file in a page.

Issues:

1.When I include two files the second file(footer.html) doesn't load,and first file(header.html)loads twice.

2.Single file loading works in FF,IE9 but doesn't work in Chrome.(Note: All files are local, I am not planning to use a web server, as this is just a prototype)

Comment: I searched further for the issue with Chrome, this is due to the policy Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Any solutions to overcome this.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/297641 post for your second problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are using same filename on each `.load`. Try something like below,

```
$(function () {
    $(".include-file").each (function () {
       $(this).load($(this).attr('file'));
     });
});
```

This should fix your first problem.

Try [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for your second problem.

Comment: Thanks SKS, That was instant. It worked, thanks you saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".include-file").load(fileName);
```

This line loads for all elements with selector of class "include-file", so for BOTH elements.

EDIT:
maybe you could also use the following (not tested)

```
$('div[file="'fileName'"').load(fileName);
```